# Get index of a group of divs when you scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of row classes and I need to print the index of each class as you scroll to the top of them.

```
<div class="row">Hello world 1</div>
<div class="row">Hello world 2</div>
<div class="row">Hello world 3</div>
<div class="row">Hello world 4</div>
<div class="row">Hello world 5</div>
<div class="row">Hello world 6</div>
```

So when I scroll to e.g. the 3rd row I want it to print "You scrolled to div nr 3".

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    $.each($(".row"), function(index, item) {
        if($(item).offset().top + $(item).height() >= $(window).height()) {
            console.log("You scrolled to div nr: " + $(item).index());
        }
    });
});
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What is wrong ?

Comment: It prints x2 values of the index. E.g. when it's 3 it prints 6. I dont understand why it does that.

Comment: x2 values means?

Comment: I mean when the index is 3, it prints 6, or when it's 2 it prints 4

Comment: why not use `index` instead of `$(item).index()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then this should achieve your requirements to printing the current div (which is at the top of the screen) based on scroll position:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    $.each($(".row"), function(index, item) {


    var top = $(item).offset().top
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop() // Use window.scrollTop rather than height

    if(offset + $(item).height() >= top) {
      console.log("You scrolled to div nr: " + $(item).index());
    }

    });
});
```

The main difference is the use of `$(window).scrollTop()` which offsets the selection of the "top most visible div" based on the current scroll position of the window

Comment: Just one thing, it should be `offset + $(item).height() >= top` otherwise it doesn't work correctly. Otherwise this answer works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you add an id or class that differentiates the DIV's this will allow you to be able to use the scroll() in Javascript. So say you add a class to your divs section_1, section_2 respectively. You can then use this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var elementTarget = document.getElementById("section-2");
  if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
  alert("You've scrolled past the second div");
}
});
```

You could change the section-2 the number 2 dynamically in your each loop. Also when you are outputting the div's make sure the individual number is being put into the classes before you try to run the scroll function.